# Ethereum Qr-code with amount?

Tags: ether, wallets, qrcode

How should a qr-code be formated with an amount in it?

The npm package ethereum-qr-code uses the following format according to EIP-67:

```
ethereum:0x7cB57B5A97eAbe94205C07890BE4c1aD31E486A8?gas=42000&value=10
```

But this format will not be recognized by every wallet on the market. Many wallets uses the "?amount=10" parameter from the bitcoin BIP21.

What format should be used, to cover most of the wallets?

In wich format is the value in EIP67 formatted? In Wei or Ether?

Is a hyprid version possible with value and amount parameter? e.g:

```
ethereum:0x7cB57B5A97eAbe94205C07890BE4c1aD31E486A8?gas=42000&value=10&amount=0.0001
```

Comment: just curious if you found out any more information re: how to encode both the ETH address and amount into a QR code in a "standardized" way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it's a decentralized world. There is no "official" way of doing things. It's also probably quite difficult to know what format "most" wallets support (if any).

I was reading through the EIP67 and it's not obvious whether the `value` should be in Ethers or Weis. A comment here suggests weis: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/67#issuecomment-323798912 and wei is the typical unit in all transactions so I'd think it's in weis. Some comments even suggested that the `value` might mean a token amount - beats me.

So basically you just have to figure out which format is supported by most wallets (or does such format even exist and do most wallets even support something like this) and then decide on what you will use.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find any decent official specification, but `Coinbase` generates QR code in such format:
`ethereum:0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa?value=500000000000000`

where `value` is in `Wei` and not `ETH` (`1 ETH` = `1,000,000,000,000,000,000 Wei`).

Comment: Well spotted. Can you provide a link to showcase this?

Comment: Metamask's QR code also has the same format.